# Places: No PlaceSelectionListener is set. No result will be delivered

Tags: android, kotlin, google-places-api

I am trying to use the google places in my project, i have set it up in a fragment as opposed to an activity, my autocomplete fragment is in a fragment. However when i try to search it i keep getting this error

```
Places: No PlaceSelectionListener is set. No result will be delivered.
```

Not sure what am doing wrong

Here is how my method looks like

```
private fun setupPlacesAutoComplete(){

        var placeFields = mutableListOf(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.ADDRESS)
        Places.initialize(view!!.context, getString(R.string.google_api_key))
        placesClient = Places.createClient(view!!.context)

        val autoCompleteFragment =
            activity?.supportFragmentManager?.findFragmentById(R.id.autoCompleteFragment) as? AutocompleteSupportFragment

        autoCompleteFragment?.setPlaceFields(placeFields)

        autoCompleteFragment?.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(object : PlaceSelectionListener{
            override fun onPlaceSelected(place: Place) {
                Toast.makeText(view!!.context, ""+place.address, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            }

            override fun onError(status: Status) {
                Toast.makeText(view!!.context, ""+status.statusMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

        })
    }
```

my fragment has this included

```
 <fragment
        android:name="com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment"
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"/>
```

Comment: Are you still having this issue? If so, first let's rule out the basics; do you have billing enabled on your project, is Places API enabled, is your API key correctly restricted?

Comment: Just tested your autocomplete code on my end and it worked without problem using my applicationContext so the issue is elsewhere; can you please post your full activity code and XML so that we can fully reproduce your issue?

Comment: No, if found my issue, it was an issue on the api key side, i had not set it up to accept google places. Thanks alot

Comment: Glad to hear & happy to have been of help :)

Comment: hey I am still getting this error.. did all the set up

Comment: Hey, my error was not with the code, i had not enabled the places api in the google console

Answer (score 1):

If you have done the set up correctly

1. Enabled Billing
2. Enabled Places API for your Project

And Still, you are not getting the result with above code means most probably this is the problem

If you want to use the AutocompleteSupportFragment inside an Activity, you can get it in this way:

```
AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment)
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autoCompleteFragment);
```

If you want to use the AutocompleteSupportFragment inside a Fragment, you can get it in this way:

```
AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment)
        getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autoCompleteFragment);
```

I had the same problem  :-)